# How to make an exclusion plot in Mathematica, e.g. draw a filled area on one side of the contour line

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to make an exclusion plot with *Mathematica* using `ContourPlot`. So I have a two dimensional function, everything higher then a certain value is excluded. In order to indicate which side is excluded, I would like to attach a light/hatched band to the contour on the side which is excluded.
As an example, my function could be something like

```
P = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 2.3}, {y, 2.5, 9}, 
 Contours -> {.5}, ContourStyle -> Black, ContourShading -> None]
```

which gives me this black parabola shaped curve in the picture. I now want a light band attached to it on one side - this I tried to show in the picture:

[image: this is what I want]

Note that I don't want the total contour to be shaded, as this would make the plot too crowded.

Actually I want something like this ROOT function does:

https://root.cern.ch/doc/v608/classTGraphPainter.html#GP02

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any ideas how this can be done? Kind regards

**Update:** thank you very much for your ideas! While your proposals really look nice, the problem I see with them is, that the width of the band of course depends on the function, and so the thickness may vary along the contour, which is not exactly what I want. I have been trying a little bit myself, but I was not really able to come up with a good solution.

I tried the following:
Getting the points of the `ContourPlot` with

```
Points = Cases[Normal@P, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]];
```

then shift them perpendicular to the Contour by a factor `k`

```
k = 0.5;
ShiftPoints = #[[1]]  + 
     k/Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]]*Cross[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] & /@ 
   Partition[Points, 2, 2];
```

then add the shifted points and the original to a Polygon and show them:

```
g = Graphics[{Gray, Opacity[0.2], 
    Polygon[Join[Points, Reverse[ShiftPoints]]]}];
Show[P, g]
```

[image]

which is kind of ok, but it gets deformed for a different Plotscale. I think it would work better, if one could get the points from the `ContourPlot`s in terms of the "image coordinates" instead of the real ones.
Maybe one of you has an idea how to improve on that?

---

*Key words:* hatched filling, custom filling

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 2:** In version 12.1 you can use the directives [`PatternFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html) or [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) for `MeshShading`:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[v f[x] + (1 - v) shiftF[f][x, .2, ar prr]], {x, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> { #4 &}, 
  MeshShading -> {None, HatchFilling[]},
  Mesh -> { {{1,Directive[Thick, Opacity[1],Red]},{0, White}}}, 
  AspectRatio -> ar, ImageSize -> 400, Evaluate @ opts]
```

[image]

With `MeshShading -> {None, PatternFilling["Diamond", ImageScaled[1/50]]}` we get

[image]

**Update:** a function to produce *parallel-looking* shifts:

```
ClearAll[shiftF, f]
shiftF [f_] := f[#] + {{0, #2}, {-#2/#3, 0}}.Normalize[f'[t] /. t -> #] &;
```

where the second argument controls the amount of "shift" and the third argument can be used to adjust for distortions caused by aspect ratio and plot range.

**Examples:**

```
cp = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 2.5, 9}, 
   Contours -> {.5}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
   ContourShading -> {None, None}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {3, 9}}];
f = BSplineFunction[Cases[Normal@cp, Line[x_] :> x, ∞][[1]], SplineClosed -> False];
opts = Sequence[Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotRangePadding -> .1, PlotStyle -> None];
prr = Divide @@ First @ Differences @ PlotRange @ cp;
ar = 1;

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[v f[x] + (1 - v) shiftF[f][x, .2, ar prr]],
 {x, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {# + .5 #2 &, # - .5 #2 &, #4 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {GrayLevel[.5], GrayLevel[.5], Directive[Thick, Red]}, MeshShading -> None, 
 Mesh -> {80, 80, {1}}, AspectRatio -> ar, ImageSize -> 400, Evaluate@opts]
```

[image]

Change the shift parameter to `-.2` to get

[image]

With `ar = 6/4` and `.2` as the second argument in `shiftF[f]` we get

[image]

and  with `ar = 1/2` and `.1` as the second argument in `shiftF[f]` we get

[image]

```
cp2 = ContourPlot[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] == .5, (x - 2)^2 + ((y - 5)/2)^2 == 1}, 
  {x, 0, 3}, {y, 2.5, 9}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick], Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
  ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {3, 9}}];
pnts = Cases[Normal@cp2, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
{fa1, fb1} = BSplineFunction[#, SplineClosed -> False] & /@ pnts;
cols = {Red, Green}; mfs = {# + .5 #2 &, #2 &}; mns = {80, 60};
i = 1;
Show[(j = i++; color = cols[[j]]; mf = mfs[[j]]; mn = mns[[j]]; 
  ParametricPlot[#, {x, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, MeshFunctions -> {mf, #4 &}, 
     MeshStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[.5, color], Thin], Directive[Thick, color]}, 
     MeshShading -> None,  Mesh -> {mn, {1}}, Evaluate@ opts]) & /@ 
  {v fa1[x] + (1 - v) shiftF[fa1][x, .2, 1/2],
   v fb1[x] + (1 - v) shiftF[fb1][x, .2, 1/2]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
fa = { Sin[4 #], Sin[3  #]} &;
ar = 5/4;
opts = Sequence[Frame -> True, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> None, Axes -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> .2, 
   AspectRatio -> ar, PlotRange -> All];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[v fa[u] + (1 - v) shiftF[fa][u, .1, ar]], 
 {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# - .5 #2 &, # + .5 #2 &, #4 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {GrayLevel[.5], GrayLevel[.5], Directive[Thick, Red]}, 
 MeshShading -> None, Mesh -> {70, 70, {1}}, Evaluate@opts]
```

[image]

With `ar = 1/2`  we get

[image]

**Related:**

- [Length of a curve parallel to a spline](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146457/125)
- [How can I offset a curve from the given data points?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152298/125)
- [Make an offset curve (parallel curve)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146140/125)

---

**Original answer:**

You can use `RegionFunction` to specify the shaded region and `MeshFunctions` to create hatched shading:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 2.5, 9}, Contours -> {.5},
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
 ContourShading -> {None, None}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {3, 9}}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> 50, MeshFunctions -> { #1&, #2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray],
 RegionFunction -> (.2 <= Cos[#] + Cos[#2] <= .501 &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can use `RegionPlot` with `MeshFunctions` to produce hatched or cross-hatched regions and use it as `Prolog` in `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 2.5, 9}, Contours -> {.5},
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], ContourShading -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {3, 9}}, 
 Prolog -> RegionPlot[.2 <= Cos[x] + Cos[y] <= .5, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 2.5, 10}, 
    Mesh -> 60, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
    MeshFunctions -> {5 #1 - #2 &, 5 #1 + #2 &}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray], PlotStyle -> None, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 10}}][[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You get the same picture using `ContourPlot[...][[1]]` as `Epilog` in `RegionPlot`

```
RegionPlot[.2 <= Cos[x] + Cos[y] <= .5, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 2.5, 10}, 
 Mesh -> 60, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {5 #1 - #2 &, 5 #1 + #2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray], PlotStyle -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {3, 9}}, 
 Epilog -> ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 2.5, 9}, 
    Contours -> {.5}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
    ContourShading -> None][[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Variations:**

```
ContourPlot[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] == .5, Sin[x] Sin[y/2] == .5}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 2.5, 9}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick], Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
 ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {3, 9}}, 
 Epilog -> {RegionPlot[.2 <= Cos[x] + Cos[y] <= .5, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 2.5, 10},
     Mesh -> 80, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
     MeshFunctions -> {5 #1 - #2 &, 5 #1 + #2 &}, 
     MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Blue], PlotStyle -> None, 
     PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 10}}][[1]], 
   RegionPlot[.2 <= Sin[x] Sin[y/2] <= .5, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 2.5, 10}, 
     Mesh -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
     MeshFunctions -> {5 #1 - #2 &, 5 #1 + #2 &}, 
     MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Pink], PlotStyle -> None, 
     PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 10}}][[1]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `MeshFunctions -> {5 #1 - #2 &}` in the first `RegionPlot` and `MeshFunctions -> {5 #1 + #2 &}` in the second to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, rather surprising shading patterns with random `MeshFunctions`:

```
ContourPlot[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] == .5, Sin[x] Sin[y/2] == .5}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 2.5, 9}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick], Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
 ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {3, 9}}, 
 Prolog -> (RegionPlot[.2 <= #[[1]] <= .5, {u, 0, 4}, {v, 2.5, 10}, 
   Mesh -> #[[2]], BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   MeshShading -> {Directive[Opacity[.3], Hue[RandomReal[]]], White}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {RandomInteger[{-1, 1}] #1 + RandomInteger[{-1, 1}] #2 &}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray], PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 10}}][[1]] & /@ 
     {{Cos[u] + Cos[v], 10}, {Sin[u] Sin[v/2], 10}})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice use of meshes. (+1)

Comment: This is a really well written answer

Answer (score 2):

You may specify additional `Contours` and related `ContourStyle` and `ContourShading`.

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 2.3}, {y, 2.5, 9},
 Contours -> {.5, 0.4},
 ContourStyle -> {None, Black},
 ContourShading -> {None, LightBlue}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

with a handle on approximate contour width

> ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},Contours -> {.2,.3,
>   12}]

[image]