# How can I enclose a closed curve with another identical slightly bigger closed curve?

Tags: plotting

I have a closed curve. I am trying to enclose this closed curve with another closed curve, which looks identical in the shape of the first closed curve, but slightly bigger. How to do this?

```
pts = {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[pts, SplineClosed -> True]}]
```

Comment: Your question is unclearly formulated: what do do you mean by 'bigger"? how about `pts = {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[pts, SplineClosed -> True], 
  BSplineCurve[1.1*pts, SplineClosed -> True]}]`?

Comment: Similar to the situation of this, enclosing a small rectangle by a bigger rectangle, all the side of the smaller rectangle is equal distance from the bigger rectangle

Comment: So in short, you wanted a *parallel curve* / *offset curve* of your original curve.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**1.** You can use [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) as follows:

```
pts = {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};

ClearAll[explode, bsf]
explode[f_] := f[#] + #2 Cross @ Normalize[f'[#]] &;

bsf = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True];

Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[pts, SplineClosed -> True], Blue, 
   Line[explode[bsf][#, .2] & /@ Subdivide[100]]}] // Framed
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Thick, Line[bsf /@ Subdivide[100]], Blue, 
   Line[explode[bsf][#, .2] & /@ Subdivide[100]]}] // Framed
```

[image]

**2.** You can also use `bsf` and `explode` with [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html):

```
ParametricPlot[{bsf@t, explode[bsf][t, .2], explode[bsf][t, -.1]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Green}, BaseStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**3.** Alternatively, you can use [`SignedRegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SignedRegionDistance.html) + [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html):

```
srd = Quiet @ SignedRegionDistance[Polygon[bsf /@ Subdivide[100]]];

ContourPlot[srd[{x, y}], {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -.5, 1}, 
 ContourShading -> None, 
 Contours -> {{.2, Blue}, {0., {Thick, Black}}}, 
 Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Use the options

```
ContourShading -> {PatternFilling["Grid", ImageScaled[1/10], 
  ImageScaled[{0, .35}]], None, None}
```

and

```
Epilog -> {Red, Disk[{0., .75}, .25], Black, Disk[{-.5, .8}, .1], Disk[{.5, .8}, .1]}
```

to get

[image]

**Related Q/As:**

- [How to make an exclusion plot in Mathematica, e.g. draw a filled
  area on one side of the contour line](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138992/125)
- [How to add 'border' to Voronoi diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221984/125)
- [Length of a curve parallel to a spline](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146457/125)
- [How can I offset a curve from the given data points?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152298/125)
- [Make an offset curve (parallel curve)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146140/125)

Comment: It is exactly what I am looking for. Could you please explain to me how you did this?

Comment: @acoustics, if we have  a function that describes the curve (luckily we have `BSplineFunction`), we can use its  normalized gradient to get the directions at each point on the curve (that's the `Normalize @ f'[t]` piece) and move each point in that direction by the desired distance.

Comment: I tried by extracting the surface normal vector at each point, then I tried scaling the points in that direction. But my results were wrong, the lines were intersecting. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @acoustics, in general parallel curves can be self-intersecting. There is a limited range of offsets where the resulting curves do not have that property.