# How can I sketch a right-angled triangle?

Tags: plotting

I would like to replicate this ellipse, but with a right-angled triangle (with smooth/rounded corners).

The formula for [this ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate):

```
h = 3; k = 3; A = -60;

xN = ((x - h)*Cos[A] + (y - k)*Sin[A]);
yN = ((x - h)*Sin[A] + (y - k)*Cos[A]);

RegionPlot[1/3 <= (xN/2)^2 + (yN/1)^2 <= 4/3, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

The reason for using RegionPlot is to remove the inner part of the ellipse. Is it possible to use this method to get a right-angled triangle, but with rounded corners like this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tri = AASTriangle[Pi/2, Pi/4, 1];

srd = SignedRegionDistance[tri];
```

We can use `SignedRegionDistance` with `ContourPlot` or with `RegionPlot` (this would be very slow):

```
ContourPlot[srd[{x, y}], {x, -.2, 1}, {y, -.2, 1}, 
  Contours -> {.1, .02}, 
  ContourShading -> {None, Yellow}, 
  ImagePadding -> 10, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[.02 <= srd[{x, y}] <= .1, {x, -.2, 1}, {y, -.2, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Yellow, PlotPoints -> 80, ImagePadding -> 10, 
 Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

We can also use the function `explode` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228527/125) to rescale the contour lines while preserving rounded corners:

```
ClearAll[explode, bsf]
explode[f_] := f[#] + #2 Cross @ Normalize[f'[#]] &;

cp0 = ContourPlot[srd[{x, y}], {x, -.1, .8}, {y, -.1, .8}, 
   Contours -> {.05}, ContourShading -> None];

mc = MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeGraphics[cp0];

bsf = BSplineFunction[mc, SplineClosed -> True];

Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[mc, SplineClosed -> True],  
  Blue, Line[explode[bsf][#, .1] & /@ Subdivide[200]]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Black, Thick, BSplineCurve[mc, SplineClosed -> True], 
  Line[explode[bsf][#, .1] & /@ Subdivide[200]], 
  Red, FilledCurve[{BSplineCurve[mc, SplineClosed -> True], 
    Line[explode[bsf][#, .1] & /@ Subdivide[200]]}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Updated**

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 4}};
in = {.7, 1};
smallpts = Mean[{#, in}] & /@ pts;
Graphics[{Orange, EdgeForm[{JoinForm["Round"], Thickness[0.035]}], 
  FilledCurve[{{Line[pts]}, {Line[smallpts]}}]}]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 4}};
in = {.7, 1};
smallpts = Mean[{#, in}] & /@ pts;
Graphics[{Red, Point[in], Green, Polygon[pts -> {smallpts}]}]
```

Or

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 4}};
in = {.7, 1};
smallpts = 
 Mean[{#, in}] & /@ pts; 
Graphics[{Orange, 
  FilledCurve[{{Line[pts]}, {Line[smallpts]}}]}]
```

Comment: `pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}};
Graphics[{FaceForm[], 
  EdgeForm[{JoinForm["Round"], Thickness[0.155], Brown}], 
  Polygon[pts], EdgeForm[{Yellow, Thick}], Polygon[pts]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0.5]`

Answer (score 3):

For a hand-drawn sketch look:

```
Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[30], ColorData[97]@1, CapForm["Round"], 
   JoinForm["Round"], Line[{{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, 0}}]}, 
  ImagePadding -> 30] // ImageEffect[#, {"Jitter", 5}] &
```

[image]