# How to plot railway tracks?

Tags: plotting, graphics

**1. What I want**

I would like to plot parametric curves approximately like these:

[image]

**2. What I did**

I googled `parallel curves` and found this resource function:

[ParallelCurve](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ParallelCurve/)

I took its definitions:

```
J[{x_, y_}] := {-y, x};

L[v0_] := Sqrt @ Simplify[v0 . v0]

ParallelCurve[a_, r_, t_] :=
 Module[{d}, d = D[a, t];
  a + r J[d] / L[d]]
```

and applied them to an `eight` curve:

```
eightc = {Sin[u], Sin[2 u]};

eightp = ParallelCurve[eightc, 0.1, u]
```

{(-0.2 * Cos[2 * u])/Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 * Cos[2 * u]^2] + Sin[u],
(0.1 * Cos[u])/Sqrt[Cos[u]^2 + 4 * Cos[2 * u]^2] + Sin[2 * u]}

**3. What I got**

```
ParametricPlot[{eightc, eightp}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 PlotPoints -> 60,
 PlotStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

Very disappointing, because the two curves are not parallel at all.

**4. Questions**

1. How can I get truly parallel curves?
2. How can I put the ties (normals) between them?

Comment: At equally separated points along the curve draw a perpendicular line segment of a fixed length.

Comment: closely related Q/As: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146457/125), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152298/125), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146140/125), [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221984/125), [5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138992/125), [6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228527/125)

Comment: the issue goes away if  you use `AspectRatio -> 1`. For `AspectRatio -> ar`, using `a + {1, 1/aratio} r J[d]/L[d]` in the definition of `ParallelCurve` makes curves look parallel. However, for this particular example,  using this approach we get  is a small bump at `u = Pi/4` and at `u =3Pi/4` .

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images (use PNG).

Comment: It should be recalled that in general, parallel curves can have self-intersections even when the starting curves do not have them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A funny one :-) (based on @lericr answer)

`m` represents number of ties.

```
curve = {Sin[u], Sin[2 u]};
m = 200;
FSS = FrenetSerretSystem[curve, u];
normal = FSS[[2, 2]];
ParametricPlot[
 curve + t normal, {u, 0, 2 Pi + (2 \[Pi])/m}, {t, -.1, .1}, 
 Mesh -> {m, {-1/10 + 1/40, 1/10 - 1/40}}, PlotStyle -> Transparent, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Transparent, Frame -> None, Axes -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

With `m=400` and `curve = {Sin[2 u], Sin[3 u]}`.

[image]

Some other examples:

[image]

[image]

With `MeshStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[4]], Directive[Opacity[1], Gray, AbsoluteThickness[5]]}`.

[image]

**Update:**

Here is code for equally spaced ties along the curve:

```
curve = {Sin[u], Sin[2 u]};
m = 200;
fu[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[Total[D[curve, u]^2]], {u, 0, x}];

mesh = Table[
   x /. FindRoot[
     fu[x] == i, {x, 0, 10}], {i, (Most@Subdivide[fu[2 \[Pi]], m])}];
FSS = FrenetSerretSystem[curve, u];
normal = FSS[[2, 2]];
ParametricPlot[curve + t normal, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, -.1, .1}, 
 Mesh -> {mesh, {-1/10 + 1/40, 1/10 - 1/40}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Transparent, BoundaryStyle -> Transparent, 
 Frame -> None, Axes -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

With `curve = {2 Sin[u], Sin[2 u]};m = 122;`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would probably start with the "center" of the tracks and expand outward along the normal vectors. You can get tangents and normals for parametric curves with`FrenetSerretSystem`. So, for example,

```
curve = {Sin[u], Sin[2 u]};
FSS = FrenetSerretSystem[curve, u];
normal = FSS[[2, 2]];
ParametricPlot[curve + t normal, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, -.1, .1}]
```

[image]

As for the ties, you now have a normal function, but since change in length isn't proportional to change in `t`, you can't just divide `t` into equal intervals to get equally spaced ties. So you'll need some calculus, I think. Also, in this particular example, the ties will look awkward at the places with tight curvature.

Answer (score 4):

Although I like and recommend the accepted answer, I would like to show an alternative solution:

```
NormalPlot[fun_, n_, sc_, {v_, b_}] :=
 Module[{nm, no, ni},
  
  nm = # / Norm[#] * sc & [Reverse @ D[fun, t] * {-1, 1}];
  
  no = Table[{fun, fun + nm}, {t, v, b, (b - v) / n}];
  ni = Table[{fun, fun - nm}, {t, v, b, (b - v) / n}];
  
  ParametricPlot[fun, {t, v, b},
   BaseStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5],
   Epilog -> Line /@ {no, ni, no[[All, 2]], ni[[All, 2]]},
   PlotRangePadding -> 0.2,
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]]]
```

The problem with the `AspectRatio` of the `Eight` figure can be solved by multiplying the x-component with 2:

```
NormalPlot[{2 Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, 140, 0.1, {-Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

```
NormalPlot[{
   Cos[t] * (Sin[t]^3 * 3 + 1)/3,
  -Sin[t] * (Cos[t]^2 * 3 + 1)/3},
 140, 0.03, {-Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

```
NormalPlot[{t, Sin[t]}, 16, 0.2, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

With a slight change of the normals function we get the tangents:

```
TangentPlot[fun_, n_, sc_, {v_, b_}] :=
 Module[{ta, to, ti},
  
  ta = # / Norm[#] * sc & [D[fun, t]];
  
  to = Table[{fun, fun + ta}, {t, v, b, (b - v)/n}];
  ti = Table[{fun, fun - ta}, {t, v, b, (b - v)/n}];
  
  ParametricPlot[fun, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   BaseStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5],
   Epilog -> Line /@ {to, ti, to[[All, 2]], ti[[All, 2]]},
   PlotRangePadding -> 1,
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]]]

TangentPlot[{t, Cos[2 t]}, 140, 1, {0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

I would like to thank all answerers and commenters for pointing me in the right direction.